# Tkinter window not opening after defining window and adding mainloop() also

Tags: python, tkinter, automation

I was trying to make a improved auto clicker with more features like:

1. press a key to save cursor position
2. execute on key press
3. kill the program on a key press
   this is the code:

```
import win32api, win32com
import pyautogui
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
import keyboard

win = tk.Tk()
cursor = (0,0)
di = 0

e = tk.Entry()

def geti():
    di = float(e.get())


l = tk.Label(text="Info:").pack()
l1 = tk.Label(text="Press q to stop clicking").pack()
l2 = tk.Label(text="Press c to copy mouse position to execute on").pack()
l3 = tk.Label(text="Press e to start executing").pack()

dl = tk.Label(text="Delay between eack click (s)").pack()
e.pack()
b = tk.Button(text="save delay time",command=geti).pack()

def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    sleep(di)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

while True:

    if(keyboard.is_pressed('c') == True):
        cursor = pyautogui.position()

    if(keyboard.is_pressed('q') == True):
        break
    
    if(keyboard.is_pressed('e') == True):
        click(cursor[0], cursor[1])
        
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while-loop blocks win.mainloop().
Instead of checking for keypresses, you could use tkinters event system with bind:

```
win.bind('key', callback)
# thanks to @acw1668's comment: added evt
win.bind('e', lambda evt: click(cursor[0], cursor[1]))
```

The lambda is necessary because you want the function to be called, not the result. From [the tkinter docs](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm):

> If you do this, Python will call the callback function before creating
> the widget, and pass the function’s return value to Tkinter. Tkinter
> then attempts to convert the return value to a string, and tells Tk to
> call a function with that name when the button is activated. This is
> probably not what you wanted.

Comment: The `lambda` should have an argument, the event object: `lambda evt: ...`.